# Threejs "geometry.colorsNeedUpdate=true" broken since r72?

Tags: three.js

Since r72 that i can't update the colors of geometry vertex, is that a known issue or am i missing something?

Here's the code that works in r71 but not in r72/73

```
 updateVertexColors: function(geometry) {
            var faceIndices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
            for(var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
                var f = geometry.faces[i];
                var n = (f instanceof THREE.Face3) ? 3 : 4;
                for(var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    var vertexIndex = f[faceIndices[j]];
                    var p = geometry.vertices[vertexIndex];
                    var color = this.lut.getColor(Math.abs(p.x));
                    f.vertexColors[j] = color;
                }
            }
            geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
        },
```

The color gets correctly assigned but it does't update on render.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `f.vertexColors[ j ].copy( color );`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are setting `colorsNeedUpdate` on `THREE.Geometry` -- or setting any `needsUpdate` flag -- and it does not appear to be working, make sure you are *not* reassigning values like so:

```
face.vertexColors[ j ] = color;
```

Instead, do this:

```
face.vertexColors[ j ].copy( color ); // or use .set(), .setHex, etc.
```

This is either a bug or a limitation in the library.

three.js r.73

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me (updating to a random color):

```
face.color.setHex('0x' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
```

Comment: You can specify a random color like so: `color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );`